# Setting a New Command (or is it an Environment?)

Tags: macros

Here's a small example of what I have to use. I have to reset the length everytime I use `\marginnote` because it restarts indenting and reformats the skip to 0.

```
\marginnote{\normalsize Some text goes here}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.15in}
```

What I would like to be able to do is redefine this behaviour so I don't have to type so much junk (and keep my tex/Sweave document cleaner)

```
\somecommand Some text goes here
```

Is there a way to get it to do so?

Comment: Why does `\marginnote` reset the lengths in the first place?

Comment: No idea, and I don't understand latex enough to figure it out*

Comment: The grouping I suggest in my answer should work to keep the length modification to "within" `\somecommand`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a grouping structure to localise any changes made by `\marginnote`:

```
\newcommand{\somecommand}[1]{% \somecommand{<text>}
  \begingroup
  \marginnote{\normalsize #1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

You would then use

```
\somecommand{Some text goes here.}
```

Comment: Perfect, I just added my \setlength's after \marginnote and it works as expected.